# Check if a JavaScript object is Map or Set (ECMAScript 2015)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What are alternative / better ways to check if a JavaScript object is Map or Set than:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(map) === Map.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(set) === Set.prototype
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use `instanceof`:

```
var foo = new Set;
foo instanceof Set; // True!
foo instanceof Map; // False!
```

Comment: @nils: It will also detect subclasses

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what you mean by subclasses. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @amphetamachine: Yours will also give true for `new (class MySet extends Set {}) instanceof Set`

Comment: @Bergi thank you for clarifying.